# Building an index buffer from a list of points

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, directx

I have a list of points in 2d space and I need to build a vertex and index buffer from them (I'm using Unity). I can't figure out how to process the points in the correct order to do this.

The star below is an example, my input is guaranteed to be valid but is unknown at compile time.

```
mesh0 = new Mesh();

// vertices for a star shape
List<Vector3> vertices0 = new List<Vector3>();
List<int> triangles0 = new List<int>();

vertices0.Add(new Vector3(150, 0, 0));
vertices0.Add(new Vector3(121, -90, 0));
vertices0.Add(new Vector3(198, -35, 0));
vertices0.Add(new Vector3(102, -35, 0));
vertices0.Add(new Vector3(179, -90, 0));

// this bit is wrong
for(int i = 0; i < vertices0.Count - 1; i++) {
    triangles0.Add(i);
    triangles0.Add(i + 1);
    triangles0.Add(i + 2);
}
mesh0.SetVertices(vertices);
mesh0.SetTriangles(triangles, 0);
```

I'd expect triangles in this case to be `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 3]` which would be a valid index buffer to render the star shape. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your triangle list isn't going to be what you say you expect it to be; based on what you've got here, your for loop will result in the list: `[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your triangles array will be

```
0, 1, 2
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5
```

The 5 is throwing you off, but you also have only 4 triangles.

You need to wrap your triangles around in this case

I would suggest reformatting your triangle generation to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vertices0.Count; i++) 
{
     triangles0.Add(i);
     triangles0.Add((i + 1) % vertices0.Count);
     triangles0.Add((i + 2) % vertices0.Count);
}
```

The modulus operator here will "wrap" your values around if they are greater than the count. I also removed the -1 from vertex count because you weren't actually adding the 5th triangle

This still doesn't make a star though it makes a pentagon, and outputs the following triangles:

```
0,1,2
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,0
4,0,1
```

It also has a lot of overlapping triangles but I'm sure you can retrofit it to do what you want from here